# how to avoid memory leak in dynamically allocated widget

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

I have to show a widgetA in a mainwindow without making it as a child of mainwindow . so if i dynamically allocate the memory space, it will trend to leak memory

```
Widget *wid = new Widget;
wid->show();
```

so i want to know how elegantly handle dynamic memory allocation of a widget without leaking.

Comment: A few extra options: 1) allocate on the stack 2) Use the `Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose` attribute on the widget

Answer (score 5, accepted):

QT is rather old school C++, so many of its examples just use raw pointers and manual calls to `delete` without conforming to RAII. This can kind of work well enough in practice since most of your `QObjects` can often be transferred ownership to a RAII-conforming container quite quickly with the exception of a few and because Qt hardly throws exceptions.

However, it does provide its own smart pointers like this:

http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/qscopedpointer.html

```
QScopedPointer<Widget> wid(new Widget);
wid->show();
// `wid` will automatically call `delete` when it goes out of scope.
```

Since you often need to transfer ownership to do things like insert child widgets to a layout, the `take` method becomes handy here which is basically equivalent to the `release` method of `std::unique_ptr`.

I would suggest just sticking to the standard C++ smart pointers like `unique_ptr`, in which case you can do this:

```
unique_ptr<Widget> wid(new Widget);
wid->show();
```

... but it's up to you whether you want to go deeper into QT or stay closer to the realm of the C++ standard.

Answer (score 1):

You may set `mainwindow` as a parent and turn on `Qt::Window` flag. This is the "Qt way".